# How do i get my function to print values for an entire list? It only seems to work for the first value

Tags: python

```
>>> M = 91    
>>> G = 2.5    
>>> R = 0.14    
>>> J = -0.033    
>>> S = [1,2] 
>>> def sigs(com):
        for i in com:
            return ((4*3.14)/3)*((1/i) + ((i*R + J*i-M**2))/((i-M**2)**2))
>>> print(sigs(S))
4.18616097606284
```

Answer (score 2):

You have returned a value for first element , instead you can use a list so store the result , and then return that list :

```
def sigs(com):
        l=[]
        for i in com:
             l.append(((4*3.14)/3)*((1/i) + ((i*R + J*i-M**2))/((i-M**2)**2)))
        return l
```

or you can use `yield` to return a generator :

```
def sigs(com):

        for i in com:
             yield ((4*3.14)/3)*((1/i) + ((i*R + J*i-M**2))/((i-M**2)**2))


print list(sigs(S))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `yield smth`. Than your function becomes an iterator.

You can use it like this

```
def func(smth):
    for I in smth:
        yield I 
for n in func([1,2,3,4]):
    print n
```

Comment: don't know why this was downvoted